# Can emacs close open LaTeX tags automatically?

Tags: latex

When using `web-mode`, typing a `</` will autocomplete with the highest level open tag name. For example, if I have an open `<div>`, `</` will be autocompleted to `</div>`.

Is it possible to get the same thing in LaTeX? For example, if I have a `\begin{foo}` tag, how can I make emacs autocomplete an `\end` or `\end{` to `\end{foo}`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the built-in `latex-mode`, `C-c C-e` runs `latex-close-block`, which closes the highest level open block.  No need to type the `\end` first.

If you're using AUCTex, `C-c ]` does the same thing, or you can use `C-c C-e` to insert a matched `\begin`, `\end` pair.

Comment: What about the matching parenthesis or the matching \left( \right)?

Comment: I don't know an out the box way to do this.  Maybe something can be rigged up out of `autopair` or `electric-pair-mode`?  This would make a good question.