# Keybinding/Function to Close Xml Tag

Tags: nxml, xml

In [LaTeX-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12803/can-emacs-close-open-latex-tags-automatically), there is `latex-close-block`, bound to <kbd>C-c C-e</kbd>.

Is there a function to programmatically close an XML tag in nXML-mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can close an XML block in nXML-mode via

```
C-c /
```

To find such functions, have a look at the mode's description, accessible via <kbd>C-h m</kbd> when in nXML-mode. It says

> <kbd>C-c /</kbd> finishes the current element by inserting an end-tag.